# When does a morphism of schemes induce a morphism of crystalline sites (not topoi)?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, crystalline-cohomology

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/94300) it is stated that the crystalline site of a scheme is not functorial in general. Is there a non-tautological characterization of morphisms of schemes which in fact do induce morphisms of crystalline sites?